# Drupal 8: How to alter the final html output?

Tags: drupal-8

I use a single drupal8 installation to serve content for multiple website's FAQ section. So I have put some custom tags like "##website_name##" in the html in article content and title. I also have blocks and custom views which display links to other articles like: related articles or popular articles etc.

I want to replace the custom tags with the respective value of the website. Is there any hook present in drupal8 which will be executed on generation of final output html but before sending it to browser so that I can place my replacement login there ?

Comment: Have you tried [``hook_tokens()``](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/token)?

Comment: Did not try that. But I already have content created with the tags of format "##website_name##" and hook_tokens required tokens of format [type:token]. Changing tags would not be possible now. So some other hook where I can use str_replace() would be great.